# Solve using Proportions/Multiplication?

Tags: fractions

How do I solve this using proportions **and** multiplication?

How much is $\dfrac 1{200}$ of $50$ percent?

I know that the answer is $0.25$, however, how would I solve that using proportions and multiplication? Can you please list both methods?

For multiplication, I have $\dfrac{1}{200}\times 0.5$, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: The answer is actually 0.25% which is 0.0025, not 0.25  So 1/200*0.5 would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you ca try to write $50\%$ as a fraction and then multiply. That would give you the correct answer as a fraction.

Otherwise, you can try to figure out how many percent $\frac{1}{200}$ is, and then see how much that is of $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{200} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{400}=.0025=\frac{\frac{1}{200}}{2}$$

Comment: What about as a proportion?

Comment: proportions are generally relative. what other form do you want?